# Best betting strategy in a number-guessing game

Tags: probability, statistics

[Edit by Milten:] Imagine I have a game where I draw a single number from $\{0, \ldots, 999\}$ uniformly at random (like a big version of roulette). A player can bet between $0$ and $10$ dollars on each number, and the payout for a winning bet is $500$ times the bet amount.

Assuming I am the casino, what is the best way to assign weighted payout to maintain a distributed sales at the same time minimizing the risk?

[Strategy thoughts by OP:] Obviously I want to evenly distribute sales across all the numbers so that I will minimize my loss and possibly ensure that I always earn some money. Is there a mathematical concept to calculate weighted payout such that I can efficiently smooth out the distribution?

Comment: "A limit of $10 per number" - What does this mean?

Comment: I think it just means this, and can you please verify Zanko? The player can bet some amount of money on as many different numbers as they like. The payout for a winning bet is $1:500$ (i.e. $500x$ dollars with a bet of $x$ dollars. The maximum bet size on any one number is $10\$$.

Comment: @Milten yes this is it thank you for phasing!

Comment: @Zanko I've done a major edit to the question to try to qualify it for reopening. You can of course cancel my edit if you want.

Comment: @Milten thank you so much! It is so much clearer now. But the only misunderstanding is that I am the casino not the player. I have edited the question, does it make more sense now?

Comment: I don't understand the question as it is now worded.  The casino doesn't appear to have any choices as to what it can do.  The description seems to me to be saying that players can bet any amount of between $0$ and $10$ on each of any set of numbers   in the range $\ 0,1,\dots,999\ $.  After drawing one number uniformly at random from that range, the casino then collects all the money bet on any of the other numbers and pays anyone who bet on that number $500$ times the amount of their bet.   What else can the casino do?

Comment: The casino can discourage player from buying the popular number by offering less payout as the number is going to fill up / or by offering higher  payout to other number that is not as popular. Casino is trying to flatten the graph. By flattening the graph casino can ensure perfect win all the time without risking losing any money. I am asking where there is a good mathematical model to guide me in term of deciding the dynamic payout assigned to the number over time